# не сохраняется сессия в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Не работает логин в Yii2 - после каждого запроса создаётся новая сессия.

Comment: Куки-то браузер принимает?

Comment: Куки каждый раз новые создаются

Comment: Возможно проблема не в самом Yii2, у меня такая же проблема была в старой версии Ларавеля, хотя в последнем Ларавеле нормально